# Suppose that CFG G defines $T^*$. Does G defines every language $L$ over the alphabet T?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Suppose that CFG G defines $T^*$. Does G defines every language $L$ over the alphabet T ?

Why the answer for this question is false ? G generates every string in the set $T^*$ and if $L$ is a language over T then $L \subseteq T^*$ so G has to generate also every string in $L$.

Comment: Every grammar defines only one language.

Comment: *The* language defined by $G$ is by definition the set of *all* strings generated by $G$; there is only one, and In this case that it’s $T^*$.